# Cambiar <option> de un <select> dinámicamente con javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo un menu donde el usuario introduce en un select la categoria y en otro select la subcategoria. Mi pregunta es si es posible cambiar las subcategorias cuando el usuario hace click en una categoria.

Esto es lo que estoy intentando:

```
<html>
      <select class="categories-select" id="categories">
            <option class="categories-option" id="category" value="Arts & Crafts">Arts & Crafts</option>
            <option class="categories-option" id="category" value="Automotive">Automotive</option>
      </select>

      <select size="10" class="categories-select" id="subcategories">
      </select>

      <script>
              function getCategory() {
                  var x = document.getElementById("categories").value;
                  var subcategories;
                  switch (x){

                       case "Arts & Crafts":
                           subcategories = ["Art Supplies", "Sewing", "Scrapbooking", "Knitting & Crochet", "Crafting", "Fabric", "Storage & Organitzation", "Beading & Jewelry Making", "Needlework", "Party Decorations", "Printmaking"];
                       break;
                  }
                  var subcategories = ""
                  for (var item of items) {
                       subcategories += "<option value="+ item + ">" + item + "</option>";
                  }
                  document.getElementById("subcategories").innerHTML = subcategories;        
             }
             document.getElementById("category").addEventListener("click", getType)
       </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es necesario que hagas uso de un `switch`, es más eficiente que guardes tus categorías y subcategorías en un objeto y luego accedas a él directamente de la siguiente manera:

```
const selectedCategory = document.getElementById("categories").value;

const categories = {
  "Arts & Crafts": ['subcategory 1', 'subcategory 2'],
  "Automotive": ['subcategory 3', 'subcategory 4', 'subcategory 5']
};

const subCategories = categories[selectedCategory];
```

Al hacer eso obtendrás un array con las subcategorias y sólo debes convertirlo en un conjunto de etiquetas `<option>`:

```
const subCategoriesElement = document.getElementById("subcategories");

const htmlOptions = subCategories
  .map(item => `<option value=${item}>${item}</option>`)
  .join('');

subCategoriesElement.innerHTML = htmlOptions;
```

Por otro lado, es mejor que utilices el evento `change` con un select en lugar de `click`.

[Aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/5tr7mp9u/) te dejo el código completo para que lo pruebes por tu cuenta.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta y por la optimización del código!